# AutoIT causing "Parameter not optional" error in RobotFramework

Tags: pycharm, robotframework, autoit

I'm using Pycharm with Python 2.7.
I'm trying to automate a test.

The AutoItLibrary is included and I can run Notepad for example.
But I'm having some problems with the included documentary.

My script so far:

```
Run  notepad.exe
ControlSend  "Unbenannt - Editor", "", "Edit1", "Test Text."
Send  ENTER
Sleep  1
WinClose  "Unbenannt - Editor"
```

But I'm getting this error on the `ControlSend` keyword:

```
com_error: (-2147352561, 'Parameter not optional.', None, None)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Robot keywords uses two or more spaces between arguments, not commas. Also, you do not need to add quotes. You can use `${EMPTY}` to represent an empty string.

Your script should look like this:

```
Control Send  Unbenannt - Editor   ${EMPTY}   Edit1   Test Text.
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure but the help file of AutoIt states this
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm
Not sure what PY has wrapped around this function